# How can I pass any id to a linq join in [HttpGet] ActionResult for Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am making a web application on MVC3, and I am using linq to communicate with the database.

I made a checkboxlist, where a user can select some options according to their choice and it gets saved in the databse table. The problem is in the Edit part.

**The whole scenario is something like this:**

The user can register as a restaurant owner or a Motel owner, I have assigned different Business_Type_Id as 1 and 2 for differentiating these two, I have assigned '2' for the Restaurant Business Type, and mapped the cuisines with the perticular business type in the same "Cuisines" table, by adding the "BusinessType" column into the table. the user will be assigned a Business_Id for their Business. I am providing a checkboxlist which generates its options from the database table "Cuisines" where I have given the cuisine list. From the front end the user can choose multiple cuisines according to their chioce what ever they provide in their restaurant. The choices may vary from one restaurant owner to the other, so I am storing the selected values for each and every Restaurant owner in a "BusinessCuisinesMapping" table, where I map the perticular BusinessId with the selected CuisineId by that perticular user.
Now to populate that cuisine list for edit or update I wrote a linq join, but I need to compare it with the Business_Id which is passed to the [HttpGet] ActionResult Edit. And this is point where I got stuck.

**This is my linq join code which I am using in the controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (var chkl = new BusinessEntities())
    {
        var data = (from CuisinesData in chkl.Cuisines
                join BusinessCuisineMappingData in chkl.BusinessCuisineMapping
                on new { CuisinesData.Id, id } equals new { BusinessCuisineMappingData.CuisinesId, BusinessCuisineMappingData.BusinessId }
                where CuisinesData.BusinessTypeId == 2
                select new CusinesDTO
                {
                    Id = CuisinesData.Id,
                        Name = CuisinesData.Name,
                        IsSelected = BusinessCuisineMappingData.CuisinesId == null ? false : true
                }).Distinct().ToList();
                ViewBag.CuisineList = data;
     }
     return View();
}
```

**This is my DTO class:**

```
public class CusinesDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to comape the "id" with the "BusinessCuisineMappingData.BusinessId" field in my LINQ join, which I am getting through the [HttpGet] Actionresult Edit(int id). It prompts me an error while I try to implement it.

Comment: What error do you get? Can you post the details?

Comment: 'public ActionResult Edit(int "id")' - typo ? should be without the quotes

Comment: There are no double quotes on "id" in my original code, I put those qutes here to give a better idea, that which value I want to use in my linq join.

Comment: The error is indicated on the text where it is written "join" at the starting, it is underlined in red by the Visual Studios, and the error message is "The type of the expressions in join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'".

Answer (score 0):

> "The type of the expressions in join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'"

This suggests the types on either side of your `JOIN` are not equal. You are getting a compiler error; should be relatively easy to check the types on either side of your `JOIN` clause.

edit: rereading what you have put, I think something like the below is what you want to do:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    using (var chkl = new BusinessEntities())
    {
        var data = (from CuisinesData in chkl.Cuisines
                    join BusinessCuisineMappingData in chkl.BusinessCuisineMapping
                    on CuisinesData.Id equals BusinessCuisineMappingData.CuisinesId
                    where CuisinesData.BusinessTypeId == id
                    select new CusinesDTO
                    {
                        Id = CuisinesData.Id,
                        Name = CuisinesData.Name,
                        IsSelected = BusinessCuisineMappingData.CuisinesId == null ? false : true
                    }).Distinct().ToList();
                    ViewBag.CuisineList = data;
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know this thing. It's not taking the 'id', it needs a field which should be related to the "CuisinesData". So my question is, how can I use the 'id' which I am getting in my "ActionResult Edit" to compare it with the "BusinessCuisineMappingData.BusinessId" field..??

Comment: What is the type of the BusinessCuisineMappingData.BusinessId field?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a local variable in the join. However, you can use it in a Where clause. So if you do

```
join ...
on CuisinesData.Id equals BusinessCuisineMappingData.CuisinesId
...
where BusinessCuisineMappingData.BusinessId == id
```

you'll have the same effect.

Comment: I have tried this thing before also, even I thought of it the same way as you, but it is not giving the desired result which I wanted, it is returning just the selected cuisines Ids only, but I want the selected options Ids with the whole listed cusines Ids. Means It should return me the each and every cusines Ids which ever are in my table, then in the second column it should return the selected cuisine Id by that perticular BusinessId, of BusinessType == 2.

Comment: Maybe you should add a sample output listing to your post. It's hard to get from words only.